# Could it be, that Chrome cancels pending Ajax requests, once the browser is being redirected to another URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this function to unlock a list the user is currently editing:

```
function unsetLock(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax.php?action=unsetLock",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: "id="+ id
  });
  return true;
}
```

When the user navigates away from the list, I have to cancel the lock:

```
unsetLock(lockID);
document.location.href='/page/to/navigate/back/to.php';
```

However this unlock sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. I think it is because `document.location.href` is executed, before the ajax call has actually been sent to the server.

How can I force to send the unlock before navigating the user to the next page?

Actually I don't need to wait for the Ajax-Reply, since I want to redirect the user, whether it succeeds, or not. I just want to make sure, it is being transferred to the server.

If I place the `document.location.href` inside the Ajax function, it will wait for the reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A really bad-mannered way to do it is to add: `async: false`, which will lock the browser up until the AJAX call is complete.
Of course, if there is a problem and the AJAX call *never* completes...

It's the quickest and easiest solution to your problem, but probably not the best.

I, personally, would have the lock only last for twenty seconds (using a timestamp in the database), and send an ajax call every ten seconds to re-lock the page (if that makes sense) using `setInterval()`.
That way the lock will unset itself a few seconds after someone leaves the page, and is good no matter what the situation (a power failure for the client wouldn't leave the page locked forever, for example).

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but why not use the `success` option in the Ajax call? This will execute whatever the outcome and makes sure it reaches the server.

```
function unsetLock(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax.php?action=unsetLock",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: "id="+ id,
    success: function(){
        document.location.href='/page/to/navigate/back/to.php';
    }
  });
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Because, I want to redirect the user, whether the Ajax request succeeds, or not.

Comment: Ok, but you also want to wait for the ajax request in case it *does* succeed. So you do have to use the `success` option, since it's the only way to know if it has succeeded. But instead of putting the redirect in there, change a `var` in there and use a `setInterval()` near the place where you are calling the `unsetLock` function. If the checked var is true, redirect, otherwise, after some loops redirect regardless. Basically, this way you will give the ajax call time to succeed. I think this is the best (only?) way since you won't get back a clear and quick 'fail' from the ajax call.

Comment: I'm not interested in whether the call succeeds or not. I only like to make sure it got sent. But I see, that this is not possible. I have to choose between waiting for the servers reply, or just having slow browsers send out the event.

Comment: Indeed, the only way to know if it got sent, is to check if it succeeded, which depends on the response. So you're left with some sort of hack. I up voted your Q because I think this is a shortcoming - for which some guru might still have a smart solution...